# sql update da error de sintaxis si cambio separador de miles y símbolo decimal en vb.net

Tags: vb.net, update, sql-server-2017

Tengo el siguiente problema en una aplicación de escritorio en vb.net y sql server: Cuando trato de actualizar un índice el catch me devuelve un error de sintaxis si elijo, en la configuración regional de windows, la coma como símbolo decimal y el punto como separador de miles. Quisiera que el programa pueda trabajar con ese formato de número pero al margen también quiero que pueda correr bien independientemente del formato que el usuario tenga configurado en su sistema. El error lo da en el último try catch, donde actualiza un índice pero es debido las variables desde y hasta del where. Saludos.

```
        Dim indiceArancel As Decimal
        Dim indiceMatricula As Decimal
        Dim indiceAdicional As Decimal
        Dim indiceCampamento As Decimal
        Dim indiceMaterial As Decimal
        Dim codigoNivel As Integer
        Dim codigoAlumno As Integer
        Dim desde As Date
        Dim hasta As Date
        Dim contador As Integer = 1
        Dim indice As Decimal
        Dim indiceTaller1 As Decimal
        Dim indiceTaller2 As Decimal
        Dim indiceTaller3 As Decimal
        '-------------------------------------------COMEDOR-----------------------------------------------------
        'Llena un dataset con historial_comedor para luego recorrerlo con un for each
        Dim tabla As String = "SELECT * FROM historial_comedor"
        Dim adaptadorTabla As New SqlDataAdapter(tabla, conexion)
        Dim datosTabla As New DataSet
        datosTabla.Tables.Add("historial_comedor")
        adaptadorTabla.Fill(datosTabla.Tables("historial_comedor"))


        For Each fila As DataRow In datosTabla.Tables(0).Rows()
            'Se selecciona, para cada fila, el índice, el nivel y la fecha desde. Si fecha hasta
            'es NULL se le asigna la fecha actual

            Try
                Dim indiceCom As String = "SELECT indice_comedor, desde, isnull((hasta), '" & Date.Now & "') as hasta 
                                           FROM historial_comedor
                                           WHERE codigo_historial_comedor = " & fila(0) & " "
                Dim adaptadorIndice As New SqlDataAdapter(indiceCom, conexion)
                Dim DatosI As New DataTable
                adaptadorIndice.Fill(DatosI)

                indiceComedor = DatosI.Rows(0)("indice_comedor")
                desde = DatosI.Rows(0)("desde")
                hasta = DatosI.Rows(0)("hasta")
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox("Error comprobando BD" & ex.ToString)
            End Try


            Try
                'Actualiza indices de arancel en vencimiento detallado en base al codigo de nivel e
                'intervalos de fechas de los aranceles
                Dim actualizaIndiceV As String = "UPDATE vencimiento_detallado 
                                                  SET indice_comedor = " & indiceComedor & "
                                                  WHERE  fecha_vencimiento >= '" & desde & "' 
                                                  AND fecha_vencimiento < '" & hasta & "'"
                Dim comandoActualizaIndiceC As New SqlCommand(actualizaIndiceV, conexion)
                comandoActualizaIndiceC.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox("Error comprobando BD" & ex.ToString)
            End Try
        Next
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es exactamente el error que te sale?

Comment: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Sintaxis incorrecta cerca de '00'.'Esta excepción se generó originalmente en esta pila de llamadas:
    [Código externo]
    Gestion.FrmEmisiónDeVencimientos.ActualizaIndices() en FrmEmisiónDeVencimientos.vb
    Gestion.FrmEmisiónDeVencimientos.GrabaVencimientos() en FrmEmisiónDeVencimientos.vb
    Gestion.FrmEmisiónDeVencimientos.BtnVencimientos_Click(Object, System.EventArgs) en FrmEmisiónDeVencimientos.vb
    [Código externo]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontré una solución pero no con visual basic.net (que cada día me desiluciona más con el manejo del formato de las variables numéricas). Pasé los updates a procedimientos almacenados en el SQL Express.

````
        Dim adaptadorTabla As New SqlDataAdapter(tabla, conexion)
        Dim datosTabla As New DataSet
        datosTabla.Tables.Add("historial_comedor")
        adaptadorTabla.Fill(datosTabla.Tables("historial_comedor"))
        concepto = "comedor"

        For Each fila As DataRow In datosTabla.Tables(0).Rows()
            'Se selecciona, para cada fila, el índice, el nivel y la fecha desde. Si fecha hasta
            'es NULL se le asigna la fecha actual

            Try
                Dim indiceCom As String = "SELECT indice_comedor, desde, isnull((hasta), '" & Date.Now & "') as hasta 
                                           FROM historial_comedor
                                           WHERE codigo_historial_comedor = " & fila(0) & " "
                Dim adaptadorIndice As New SqlDataAdapter(indiceCom, conexion)
                Dim DatosI As New DataTable
                adaptadorIndice.Fill(DatosI)

                indiceComedor = DatosI.Rows(0)("indice_comedor")
                desde = DatosI.Rows(0)("desde")
                hasta = DatosI.Rows(0)("hasta")
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox("Error comprobando BD" & ex.ToString)
            End Try


            Try
                Dim comandoIndiceC As New SqlCommand("UPD_indiceComedor", conexion)
                comandoIndiceC.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                Dim adaptadorIndice As New SqlDataAdapter(comandoIndiceC)
                With comandoIndiceC.Parameters
                    .Add(New SqlParameter("@indiceComedor", SqlDbType.Decimal)).Value = indiceComedor
                    .Add(New SqlParameter("@desde", SqlDbType.Date)).Value = desde
                    .Add(New SqlParameter("@hasta", SqlDbType.Date)).Value = hasta

                End With

            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox("Error comprobando BD" & ex.ToString)
            End Try
        Next  ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Acabo  de hacer una prueba. Comenté el where y sigue dando el mismo error por lo tanto el problema está en la variable  indiceComedor. No entiendo porque en otros formularios del mismo proyécto donde se leen, graban y actualizan tablas con decimales todo funciona bien sin importar la configuración regional. Sabiendo que el problema es por la variable con los decimales tal vez tenga que hacer algun tipo de formateo de la variable con format() pero no se exactamente como.